# FileNotFoundError file does not exist, but it does exist when using df = pd.read_csv. Python 3, Spyder IDE

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm attempting to compile some stock data that I have downloaded and stored locally. the locally stored data is in one folder, and all contain non-corrupted csv files.  This is the code I'm using to read the folder containing all of my saved csv files:

```
df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker.replace('.'and'-'and',','')))
```

When i run my full program, the ticker BRK.B always shows up as FileNotFoundError:

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'stock_dfs/BRK-B.csv' does not exist
```

The error is interesting because in my "stock_dfs" folder, the ticker is written as BRK.B and I thought the pandas reader couldn't identify a ticker with a '.'.

Attempting to fix this error I added the code below because I thought it might have to do with the '.', but then it changed to a '-', then to a ',' and when i finally covered all of those it still gives the error message with a '-': (the 'change' i'm referring to is in the punctuation between 'BRK' and 'B' when the error is printed.)

```
ticker.replace('.'and'-'and',','')))
```

but I still receive the FileNotFoundError:

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'stock_dfs/BRK-B.csv' does not exist
```

I looked at other questions like CSV file doesn't exist - pandas dataframe, but even then when I provided a full path to the folder, and even to the BRK.B csv file, it produced the same error as above.  The tip of specifying the path to the folder did not help, and I for the life of me cannot figure out why it keeps changing the punctuation to one of the ticker's in the error, as well as not find a csv file that clearly is there.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[here is an image of the BRK.B file in the folder, as well as opened up in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRkWK.png)

Comment: What is `ticker` here? Your string interpolation is incorrect: Python is telling you that it is looking for `BRK-B.csv` but your filename is `BRK.B.csv`. Note that `'.'and'-'and','` evaluates to `','` (try it).

Comment: the string is part of a for loop that identifies "ticker" .  Why is python looking for BRK-B.csv?

Comment: Where do you get the values for `ticker` from?

Comment: i have a file saved with all 500 of the S&P tickers which I retrieved from google finance api.  ticker is defined as the information being retrieved from google from each and every one of those "ticker" stock symbols that I also have saved in a csv file.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Please post your full code (up to the `read_csv` call that's erroring), after you review how the suggestions for [creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). An MCVE really helps us help you.

Comment: I figured out the issue.  The stock ticker symbols that I downloaded were slightly different than the stock data information (and their ticker symbols) that i downloaded from google finance api.  It turned out that Wikipedia (where I got the ticker symbols) used 'BRK,-B' whereas google finance used 'BRK.B'.  When i commented out all the ticker.replace stuff the data compiled successfully.

Comment: @Q.Wieber can you post your comment as an answer and accept it, so we can close this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, the folder separator is `\` and not `/`.

Try the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs\{}.csv'.format(ticker))
```

If you want system independent separator, use `os.sep` after `import os`, or just `from os import sep`.

If you want to replace a lot of symbols into nothing, try:

```
symbols = '-,.'
for c in symbols:
    if c in ticker:
        ticker.replace(c, '')
```

There is clearly a discrepancy between the ticker names and file names, but without knowing how you named your files compared to ticker names from Google, it's hard to guess the specific error.

To find the name, you can try to find it in the folder:

```
from os import listdir, getcwd
from os.path import isfile, join
print([f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f)) and f.upper().startswith('BRK')])
```

That will list all files in the `mypath` folder that starts with **BRK**.

And, as a last not:

> The error is interesting because in my "stock_dfs" folder, the ticker is written as BRK.B and I thought the pandas reader couldn't identify a ticker with a '.'.

There is nothing wrong with having '.' (dot) in the file name, i.e. you could perfectly have a file called *some.file.with.long.name.txt.csv*

Comment: I did mend the folder separators, yet I am still receiving the error

Comment: What is the error? "File b'stock_dfs/BRK-B.csv' does not exist"? Your file is `stock_dfs\BRK.B.csv`, right?

Comment: this is the error "FileNotFoundError: File b'stock_dfs/BRK-B.csv' does not exist"

Comment: Your file, according to your image, is called BRK.B (and assumable a .csv extension) and not BRK-B.csv, which is what `ticker` value seems to be. The ticker value comes from somewhere, but apparently not from reading the files in the folder?

Comment: I saw your other comment. There is clearly a discrepancy between ticker names and file names, but without knowing how you named your files compared to how you named your ticker names, it's hard to guess the error. I've updated my answer to show how you can replace multiple values.

Comment: I have found the issue.  When i get the ticker symbols from Wikipedia and compile them into a csv file, all tickers that use '.' are supplemented with a ',' then '-' when printed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. When i get the ticker symbols from Wikipedia and compile them into a csv file, all tickers that use '.' are supplemented with a ',' then '-' when printed.